# How to modify a string and return it?

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to modify a string and then return it in C. But the code doesn't work well. When I run the function in `main`, the `wordOfNum` returns an empty string

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char *wordOfNum(int number, int spec) {

    char *word = malloc(strlen("Example") + 1);

    if (spec == 0) {
        switch (number) {
        case 1:
            strcpy(word, "one");
            break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(word, "two");
            break;
        case 3:
            strcpy(word, "three");
            break;
        case 4:
            strcpy(word, "four");
            break;
        case 5:
            strcpy(word, "five");
            break;
        case 6:
            strcpy(word, "six");
            break;
        case 7:
            strcpy(word, "seven");
            break;
        case 8:
            strcpy(word, "eight");
            break;
        case 9:
            strcpy(word, "nine");
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (spec == 1) {
        switch (number) {
        // case 1: return "one";
        case 2:
            strcpy(word, "twenty");
            break;
        case 3:
            strcpy(word, "thirty");
            break;
        case 4:
            strcpy(word, "fourty");
            break;
        case 5:
            strcpy(word, "fifty");
            break;
        case 6:
            strcpy(word, "sixty");
            break;
        case 7:
            strcpy(word, "seventy");
            break;
        case 8:
            strcpy(word, "eightty");
            break;
        case 9:
            strcpy(word, "ninety");
            break;
        }
    }
    return word;
}

void exercise1() {

    char num[4];
    printf("This is exercise 1: \n");
    printf("Enter a 4 digit number: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", num);
    printf("%s thoundsand %s hundred %s %s", wordOfNum(num[0], 0), wordOfNum(num[1], 0), wordOfNum(num[2], 1), wordOfNum(num[3], 0));
}

int main() {

    exercise1();
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is about scoping. At `wordOfNum` I'm using a `switch` nested in an `if` so the `word` doesn't change as supposed. When I `strcpy` `word` 1 level up, which means only in a single if, the `word` can change

Comment: What does "doesn't work well" mean? What problems are you having?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you could also solve the task without allocating the string dynamically, as in `case 1: return "one";` and then just change the return type to `const char*`.

Comment: Assuming you type in the correct input, `num[0]` will be a character such as `'1'`, not a number such as `1`. Assuming ASCII, `'1'` has the numeric value 49, not 1.

Comment: @DeiDei Even better, just look it up in a static array.

Comment: I edit the question with the specified error

Comment: Note `"eightty"` did not pass the spell check.  Also "thoundsand".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is you are mixing `int`s and `char`s, what you pass as a parameter is actually a `char`, a simple way to fix this is to convert the `char` you pass as `number` argument to `int`. If you want to avoid this conversion you can change your `switch`es from `case 1:...` to `case '1':...`, all of them, of course.

You should also use `char num[5];` space for a null terminator, and `scanf("%4[^\n]%*c", num);` to avoid buffer overflow.

There is still the matter of verifying if the inputted value is really a 4 digit string otherwise the results will not be the expected.

[Demo](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/TrustyOldlaceSemicolon)

```
char *wordOfNum(int number, int spec) { //or char number

    //...

    int num = number - '0'; //convert char to int

    if(num > 9 || num < 0){ //check if input is a 4 digit number
        puts("The input must be a 4 digit number!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // or handle it as you see fit
    }

    if (spec == 0) {
        switch (num)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
    else if (spec == 1) {
        switch (num)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

As mentioned by [@DeiDei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5212827/deidei) in the comment section, you could avoid `malloc` by simply using `word = "one";` etc. instead of `strcpy(word,"one");` and change the return type to `const char*` to avoid attemps to edit the string literals.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very well. May I ask this? The problem is I pass an ```int``` instead of ```char```. So can I pass the argument as a ```char```? Like ```(char number)```. I tried but it doesn't work. Is there a way that we can avoid coercion like the solution you provided above ?

Comment: @Mark, yes you can pass it as a `char` but can leave it as is, it's legal to pass a `char` to an `int` argument, so the results are the same.

Comment: @Mark, I guess I didn't read your comment to the end, if you don't want to convert it you can change your `case 1:...`to `case '1':...` etc., this way no conversion is needed.